# Matlab - Partial Least Squares

Tags: matlab, regression

Can you please tell me how to perform Partial Least Squares in matlab? Suppose my input is X (size: n x p, n observations, p parameters), and my output is Y(p x 1). For me, n = 800,000
and p = 8. I know the method call is plsregress(X,Y,ncomp), but what exactly is ncomp? What would make sense in my case? 
Thanks

Comment: I am doing [xL,yL,xS,yS,bPLS] = plsregress(input, output); and even though all my data is real, I am getting complex output. How is this possible? Pleas help

Comment: Check the examples on http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/plsregress.html for how to determine the ncomp.